# Is it possible to set DateTimePicker to dropdown the monthCalendar by default?

Tags: winapi

To avoid a duplicate control to CreateWindowEx(0,MONTHCAL_CLASS,...), it is expected to have  DateTimePick_Class control showing DropDown Calendar defaultly.

```
HWND hwndDP = CreateWindowEx(
                             0,
                             DATETIMEPICK_CLASS,
                             TEXT("DateTime"),
                             WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | DTS_SHOWNONE,
                             50, 20,200,25,
                             hWnd,
                             (HMENU)ID_DATETIME_PICKer,
                             hInst,
                             NULL);
```

But it seems that one has to know the control of dropdown arrow button say "ARROW_BTN", like this

```
  SendMessage(hwndDP,WM_NOTIFY,(int)ARROW_BTN,(NMHDR)DTN_DROPDOWN);
```

or

```
  SendMessage(hwndDP,DTN_DROPDOWN,0,0);
```

what is the command to retrieve the control ID or some other tricks behind?

Comment: [`DTM_GETDATETIMEPICKERINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/dtm-getdatetimepickerinfo) allows you to retrieve handles to the child controls. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: That said, notifications are generated **by** the control so that clients can respond to certain events. You cannot send a notification **to** the control.

Comment: There is no message defined to display a DateTimePicker's dropdown calendar from code. It only appears in response to user input. If you want to show a calendar in your UI, use a [Month Calendar control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-reference) instead of a DateTimePicker.

Comment: Thanks, one additional Month Calendar control can be the remedy, but it seems awkward.